# Sorting a list in c# (custom defined sorting rules)

Tags: c#, list, split, swap

I have a list of string called **choosedGroupList** consisting of 5 items. Each item represents a group,
For example: L1andL4 means that L1 will be grouped with L4.
Another example: L1,L4andL5,L6 means that the group L1,L4 will be grouped with the group L5,L6

[image: choosedGroupList]

I am trying to sort this list to be like this:

**L1andL4

L5andL6

L1,L4andL5,L6

L2andL1,L4,L5,L6

L3andL2,L1,L4,L5,L6**

So I wrote this code to perform this task,

```
 //sorting choosedGroupList
        for (int k = 0; k < choosedGroupList.Count; k++)
        {
            for (int j = k + 1; j < choosedGroupList.Count; j++)
            {
                string[] parts = choosedGroupList[j].Split(new string[] { "and" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                if (parts[0] == choosedGroupList[k].Replace("and", ",") || parts[1] == choosedGroupList[k].Replace("and", ","))
                {
                    string[] parts2 = choosedGroupList[k + 1].Split(new string[] { "and" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    //if (parts[0] != parts2[0] || parts[1] != parts2[1])
                    //{
                        String Temp = choosedGroupList[k + 1];
                        choosedGroupList[k + 1] = choosedGroupList[j];
                        choosedGroupList[j] = Temp;
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
```

I have no exceptions in the code but, I do not get the desired results.

After executing the code this is the result:

**L1andL4

L1,L4andL5,L6

L2andL1,L4,L5,L6

L5andL6

L3andL2,L1,L4,L5,L6**

Comment: What is the *rule* to be followed here? What algorithm do you apply in your mind to come up with the expected results.

Comment: Start with writing a comparison routine using the `System.Collections.IComparer` interface (there are other ways, but lets keep it simple and straightforward here) that just compares two of those strings according to your requirements. The return value should be an integer that indicates whether string #1 is smaller than string #2 (result `-1`), string #1 is larger than string #2 (result `1`), or whether string #1 is the same as string #2 (result `0`).

Comment: There is no need to write a complete sorting routine by hand, because with such a custom comparer based on `IComparer`, several functions/collections can do the sorting according to your needs. Also, a comparison routine alone is easier to test/trouble-shoot/debug than a bunch of code in nested loops. ;-)

Comment: Correction: The interface i meant in my 1st comment is not `System.Collections.IComparer` but rather `System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<string>`. Sorry for the hiccup...

Answer (score 1):

Assumption 1: you wish to sort first by number of 'L's then by the numbers following the 'L's.

The major issue in the code given is that you never check the length of the arrays, so L1,L4 will always sort before L5 because L1 sorts before L5.

If you split on 'and' separately from ',' and sort on length of the array split from ',' first before sorting on the contents of that array, then it should match your proposed sort order.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a Dictionary?

```
    public static Dictionary<string, int> YourDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> returnDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        returnDict.Add("L1andL4", 1);
        returnDict.Add("L5andL6", 2);
        returnDict.Add("L1,L4andL5,L6", 3);
        returnDict.Add("L2andL1,L4,L5,L6", 4);
        returnDict.Add("L3andL2,L1,L4,L5,L6", 5);

        return returnDict;
    }
```

Then iterate over the Dictionary:

```
        var theDictionary = clsProdDesign.YourDictionary();
        var items = from pair in theDictionary orderby pair.Value ascending select pair;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in items)
        {
            //do whatever
        }
```

Comment: And now that I think more about what you're trying to do, I'd probably just build a table in SQL to accomplish this task.  Have a column for your selection, your grouping, and the sort order.